# Core Animation: Do an animation only on a specified-portion of a layer (iOS)

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer

I'm pretty much desperate here looking for a way to add an animation to a `CALayer` but make it apply only to a part of the layer. Or if it's even possible.

I'm trying to animate a part of the text (currently using `UILabel`) but keep the rest as-is.

Here's a good example:

A counter, when you add/remove a count only one digit changes.

Thanks

Edit 1:

I'm trying to edit the position of a ***/part/*** of the text.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Animate the transform/alpha/position of a part of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is NOT possible. Core animation applies to an entire layer. UIView animation applies to an entire view.

If you want to animate part of a layer/view, you't going to need to cut it into pieces and animate just the part you want to change.

An exception to this is that you can animate the path of a CAShapeLayer. As long as the path keeps the same structure (number/type of control points) then changes to the path get animated.

If you had a shape layer where the text was defined using a path, and you could devise a way to transform the path while keeping the same number and type of control points, you could make part of the shape change.

It's also possible to animate changes to a layer's mask. With that, you can reveal or hide part of a layer, which could give you an effect like animating part of a layer. You could make the middle portion of a layer fade away to transparent, for example.

Comment: Thanks Duncan for your input!

So if I understand your statement correctly, I should add a mask to the portion that needs to be modified and work from there?

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Create a new layer the same size as the layer you want to mask. Add it as the mask for the layer you want to modify. The alpha channel of the mask layer determines which parts of the layer are shown. (Where the mask is opaque, your layer shows, and where it's transparent, the layer is hidden.) You can either install a CGImage in the mask layer, or make the mask layer a CAShapeLayer and install a CGPath in the shape layer. BTW, how about accepting my answer and up-voting it?

Comment: Thanks Again Duncan. No worries, I was awaiting your response for the +1.